# Python numpy operation does not compute correctly

Tags: python, numpy

I stumbled onto something very peculiar and am wondering if it is a Python bug or it's something I did not properly understand with regard to Numpy arrays.

I'm computing the Kernel trick:

```
(c + np.matmul(x1, x2.T)) ** n
```

n = nth power; c = free parameter

Let x1 be (3,6) and x2 = (10, 10)

Computing the matmul should result in 90.
However when I use c=2 and n=5; the result is incorrect! It gives -1999119360 instead of 6590815232!

Am I doing something wrong with the code? Or is it a bug? Because when you decrease n, the results are correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of operation `c + np.matmul(x1, x2.T)` is a `numpy.int32`. The problem seem to be when using the `**` operation on this class. The result will also be `numpy.int32`. But the max value for this type is 2147483647 where as the computation result is 6590815232 in your example. Which causes an  integer overflow. I hope you understand.

Converting the result of `np.matmul(x1, x2.T)` to `int` class gives the right output. ie:

```
(c + int(np.matmul(x1, x2.T))) ** n
```

Another option is to convert the value to `numpy.int64` like:

```
(c + np.int64(np.matmul(x1, x2.T))) ** n
```

Comment: So is it a Python bug? It works without int() for lesser n, but when you increase n, it gives incorrect result!

Comment: An integer overflow is what happens I've explained it here.